# Xamarin Forms ListView Bindings don't get updated

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a ListView with a ViewModel. In my ListView I have a few Labels with Text that is bound to the objects in the ItemSource. Now when I change a value in the ViewModel of an item in the ObservableCollection, nothing changes on the screen!

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class VM_DeviceList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public ICommand cmdDeleteDevice
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<int>((x) => DeleteDevice_Handler(x));
        }
    }

    public ICommand cmdTogglePower
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<int>((x) => TogglePower_Handler(x));
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<DisplayedDevice> _knownDeviceList;
    public ObservableCollection<DisplayedDevice> knownDeviceList
    {
        get
        {
            return _knownDeviceList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_knownDeviceList != value)
            {
                _knownDeviceList = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("knownDeviceList"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my class for the ObservableCollection:

```
public class DisplayedDevice : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string StateShown { get; set; }
    public string deviceImage { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string PowerStateColor { get; set; }
    public string DeviceImageColor { get; set; }

    public string DeviceImage
    {
        get
        {
            return deviceImage;
        }

        set
        {
            deviceImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding knownDeviceList}" SelectionMode="None" RowHeight="90" ItemTapped="device_Clicked" x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <AbsoluteLayout HeightRequest="70" Margin="20,10,20,10">
                    <StackLayout Opacity="0.3" BackgroundColor="White"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,3,0,0"
                        FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="24" TextColor="White" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding StateShown}" FontSize="18" TextColor="White" />

                            <!-- <Image Source="power" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" /> -->
                            <controls:IconView x:Name="btnPower" Source="power" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5"
                                            Foreground="{Binding PowerStateColor}">
                                <controls:IconView.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.cmdTogglePower, Source={x:Reference MyListView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
                                </controls:IconView.GestureRecognizers>
                            </controls:IconView>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now what I expected to happen, was that when I click on the IconView I change the IconView color and the label with the StateShown binding. But nothing changes when I click on the IconView!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your viewmodel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: I already tried that, but I think I am doing something wrong. I set the PropertyChanged in the knownDeviceList, but still nothing happens on the screen! Can you show how I need to implement it the right way in my case?

Comment: Please post the code showing how you implemented it.

Comment: Please add your `DisplayedDevice` class to query. You need to call OnPropertyChanged on each property in that class for UI to reflect on its change.

Comment: I updated my code above

Comment: @Nikhileshwar I think I have done that in the class ?

Comment: You have called the OnPropertyChanged only for `DeviceImage` Property. Only changes in `DeviceImage` will change in UI. Also `deviceImage`(smaller case one need not be public. It can be private). Do you get my suggestion?

Comment: No, not really xD

Comment: Could you check the answer I uploaded. Add OnPropertyChanged call to every property you want to reflect change in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `OnPropertyChanged` method call to every property on `DisplayedDevice` for those you want the UI to notice.

```cs
public class DisplayedDevice : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            Id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string state;
    public string State
    {
        get
        {
            return state;
        }
        set
        {
            state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    ......

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVVMHelpers NuGet Package and implement the ObservableObject Class from the NuGet directly to  DisplayedDevice class and you need to make all the properties with a reference to the private variable.

```
public class DisplayedDevice: ObservableObject
    {

        string _textField = string.Empty;
        public string TextField
        {
            get => _textField;
            set => SetProperty(ref _textField, value);
        }
        bool _isBarChartVisible = false;
        public bool IsBarChartVisible
        {
            get => _isBarChartVisible;
            set => SetProperty(ref _isBarChartVisible, value);
        }
}
}
```

Every public property should be backed by a private property of the same type. This is important so that any change in any property will be reflected on the UI using INotifyPropertyChanged